# canonical correlation analysis explained variance interpretation

Tags: interpretation, canonical-correlation

I´m performing a canonical correlation analysis (cca) between two sets of variables, let´s call them `physiological` and `clinical`.

I carried out this cca for both sets of variables, controlling for a third variable and removing the outliers. As one of the sets has just three variables this I got three coefficientes for the explained variance:

```
[1] 0.4692337 0.2514539 0.1120628
```

This means the first linear combinations of the variates explain 46.9% of the variance, and the second explains 25%.

However when I perform this CCA with a condition for a one of the variables I get:

```
[1] 0.7968007 0.6419638 0.4892254
```

Which has sum of > 1.

Would be a correct interpretation that the first linear correlation explains 79% of the variance, and the second one explains 64% of the variance not explained by the first?